# Toggle visibility of div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I think the problem was I was writing `.innerHtml` and overwriting the form elements, is that correct, sorry to waste your time.

---

I am trying to toggle the visibility of a div containing some form elements. The idea is that if the person selects a particular value of a select box an `onchange` event handler will make a particular div containing those form elements disappear.When they choose any other option the div will reappear.

```
if(chosen_option != option_that_makes_id dissappear){
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'the if statement is working';
}else if(chosen_option == option_that_makes_id dissappear){
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```

The problem I am having is the the div will disappear properly but then when I select another value from the check list the div reappears but no longer contains the form values.

I put the `.innerHTML` in the if statement and then when that condition is met I just see the text the if statement is working but not the form elements.
Is this a feature of JavaScript or is am I doing something wrong?

Here is the full unedited JavaScript function:

```
function change_div_visibility(id,select_id,div){//id is the id of the select box and the name of the div which you want to change the visibility of .
 var select_option = document.getElementById(select_id).options;
 var chosen_option = select_option[select_option.selectedIndex].value;
 if(chosen_option != id){
  document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = 'the if statement is working';
 }else if(chosen_option == id){
  document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = 'the else statement is working but for some reason the visibility of the div is not changing. ';
 }
}
```

and the section of the form which I am trying to manipulate:

```
<p><label for='buying_options'>Select Buying Option</label><select onchange=\"change_div_visibility('new_buying_1','buying_options1','div1')\" id='buying_options1' name='buying_options1'><option value='undefined'>Select Buying Option</option>
   <option value='new_buying_1'>New Buying Option</option>";
   $y = '';
   foreach($buying_options_arr as $key=>$value){
            $x.= "<option value='$key' >$value</option>";
   $y.= '&lt;option value='.$key.'&gt;'.$value.'&lt;/option&gt;';
   }
        $x.= "</select> or</p> ";
  $x.= "<div id='div1' >
  <p><label for='add_new_buying_option'>Add new Buying Option: </label><input id='add_new_buying_option' type='text' name='add_new_buying_option1' /></p>\n";
  $x.= "<p><label for='compression' >New Unit Quantity: </label><input type='text' id='compression' name='unit_quantity1' /></p>\n
  ";
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, are you saying that you enter values into the form elements (which are in the div), choose an option so that the div disappears, choose another option so that the div reappears, and then the values you entered in the form elements are gone?

Comment: Can you post the full JavaScript code for this so that we can get a better understanding?

Comment: No the form elements themselves are gone i can't see the input fields

Comment: Andrew, what browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Ill just put my full code up there. Give me a moment

Comment: Damn, i just realised that i was overwriting the content of the divs myself. sorry to waste you time thanks for the suggesting of using display

Comment: document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "yadayada" will overwrite the existing contents, i.e. <label for='add_new_buying_option'... Are you sure you're OK with that?

Comment: Could you do a view source in your browser, and copy-paste to show the rendered markup, rather than the server-side source code? perhaps there's an error in the HTML generation which is causing your javascript problems...?

Comment: ...for example, does `key` contain an apostrophe? etc...

Comment: I think the issue was me overwriting the contents of the div problem solved, but i will put up the rendered code if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing style.display to 'none' or 'block' instead?

Comment: This is not quite the same thing. Setting visibility to "hidden" hides the element from view, but it still takes up space. Setting display to "none" is the equivalent of wiping the element out; it no longer takes up any space.

Comment: Its not wiped out, it remains there, just takes no space.

Comment: display is far and away the property chosen to implement the requested functionality.  Large blocks of empty space are ugly and (gasp!) "confuse the user."

Comment: Salman: Correct, I meant "wiped out" in the sense that it takes up no space. It can still be unhidden of course :)

No Refunds No Returns: Agreed, but since this is the property he was changing, I figure he has a reason to use it over display.